# "Invalid Input" error when trying to set a service center number

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sms, lg-g4

On an LG G4 (Android 6.0), I'm unable to send SMS messages, when I called my provider they told me that I need to change the Service center number in the Messaging app settings. Currently it's `+7`, when I try to change it to the correct number (`+97253989999`) I get an "Invalid input" error.

### UPDATE

When I restarted the device, the problem corrected itself and the correct number was set as the service center number.

Does anyone knows what the cause for this can be (it's not the first time this happens)?

Comment: Tried `02989999` ?

Comment: @beeshyams, the same, "Invalid input".

Comment: My provider is "Hot mobile" in Israel. I've checked with someone else who has the same provider and they have that number in their settings.

Comment: Suggest delete the APN settings altogether and s start fresh . Settings > more> mobile network > AP N. This should make it like installing a SIM in new phone and ask your provider of they send configuration settings by SMS ( Indian provides do this - just need to click on SMS and settings are applied ). If they don't apply manually. Also clear the cache of messaging app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the phone fixed the issue.

Since then it happened maybe one or two more times, restarting the phone fixes this every time. I couldn't find a permanent solution for the problem, but restarting the phone works well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and finally found that the issue was SIM.
Changed my SIM by contacting service provider and it worked fine with me :)